# Find duplication before insert to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How i can check before insert into gridview , my insertion code is below it is button click.

```
if (Session["dtInSession"] != null)
    dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dtInSession"];
    DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
    dr["AccessoryName"] = drpAccessories.SelectedItem;
    dr["ConditionName"] = drpConditions.SelectedItem;
    dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
    Session["dtInSession"] = dt1; 
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt1;
    grvList.DataSource = dt1;
    grvList.DataBind();
```

i tried this way but for sure it will check only the last selected item not other rows inserted already.

```
if (grvList.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  foreach (GridViewRow gr in grvList.Rows)
  {
    accessorucheck = ((Label)gr.FindControl("txtAccessories")).Text;
    if (accessorucheck == drpAccessories.Text)
    {
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation1", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Accessory Alredy Added, Please change the condition if needed.')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
      if (Session["dtInSession"] != null)
        dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dtInSession"];
        DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["AccessoryName"] = drpAccessories.SelectedItem;
        dr["ConditionName"] = drpConditions.SelectedItem;
        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["dtInSession"] = dt1;
        grvList.DataSource = dt1;
        grvList.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataView.ToTable [MSDN DataView.ToTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/a8ycds2f(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (Session["dtInSession"] != null)
        dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dtInSession"];

    DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
    dr["AccessoryName"] = drpAccessories.SelectedItem;
    dr["ConditionName"] = drpConditions.SelectedItem;
    dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
    Session["dtInSession"] = dt1; 
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt1;
// 
DataView view = new DataView(dt1);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "AccessoryName", "ConditionName");
grvList.DataSource = distinctValues;
grvList.DataBind();
```

Comment: It will only hep you to show the distinct, whereas it will not show any error message while insertion.

Comment: thanks ihtsham. its working with your code now. really thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the way the ihtsham has mentioned above however you will still end up with a record being inserted and then omitted again adding unnecessary overhead.

I would rather after getting the datatable from the session variable use the `select` command to check if a row like that exists. You could use something similar to this, dont think the syntax will be perfect, as my ASP.Net is rusty but it should get you on the right track.

```
if (dt2.Select("AccessoryName = 'Var' AND ConditionName = 'Var2'").Rows.Count == 0)
{
   //Insert code here
}
else
{
   //Code to execute when duplicate added
}
```